# No Account number or Address in listtransactions for generated blocks

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, block

I am in the need (for my app development) of having more information printed with the "listtransactions" of the bitcoind daemon.

For blocks generated it shows the account as "" and no bitcoin address is shown either.
Why in fact not? The blockexplorer shows the address that "mined" the block, and the mapping of the address to the account number works perfectly when receiving coins, why not for generated blocks?

Even this request doesnt make it into the mainstream client, any help telling me where in the code to put it (if at all technically feasable) is very much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to your question here, you may also want to create an issue on the [Bitcoin GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues) for your feature request. As for the solution, I know Bitcoin keeps the whole blockchain available and searchable, that's how sites like BlockExplorer work, I'm just not 100% sure of how to access that particular database. I'm sure someone in our community will know, though :)

Comment: Come to think of it, would a private [Bitcoin-abe](https://github.com/jtobey/bitcoin-abe) server work for your purposes? At the very least you should be able to find code to parse the blockchain somewhere in there, and it's Python so it should be easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There is an embryo of a  [patch](https://github.com/sgimenez/bitcoin/commit/d3deed5e41b15195a4f24dec458bb065121a1949) on github which was precisely meant to solve this issue. It was announced on the dev mailing list but never received much attention. Now it's a bit outdated (the [latest](https://github.com/sgimenez/bitcoin/commit/34ca1aec9fa92b25796ba6adaaf4ba888379091d) merge with master is from Sep 26). Maybe you can start from here.